# Listbox custom selected background color - InvalidArgument

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I'm receiving an unhandled exception when executing a .net application:

```
InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index
```

The code itself is used to change a selected item's background color in a listbox (winforms):

```
private void listbox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    Brush bg = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 100, 100));

    e.DrawBackground();
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Brush brush = ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected) ? bg : new SolidBrush(e.BackColor);
    g.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(((ListBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

The exception indicates that it is the `Brush brush = ...` line, but I don't understand why it's throwing this exception.

Comment: Is the code you're using to debug up to date with the version of the program you're running? It seems like the line with `(ListBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString()` would be throwing the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before using `e.Index` check it's value

```
if(e.Index >= 0)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString(((ListBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have received this exception, then you might want to consider being defensive before the block of code by adding a check to see that the index is greater than 0.

```
if (!e.Index < 0)
{
e.DrawBackground();
Graphics g = e.Graphics;
Brush brush = ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected) ? bg : new SolidBrush(e.BackColor);
g.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds);
e.Graphics.DrawString(((ListBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

By doing this you will only execute the code when the event is raised from the source with valid arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think it's indicating this line:

```
... (ListBox)sender).Items[e.Index] ...
```

It seems to be trying to get the `-1` element in the `ListBox`.

To confirm it, place a breakpoint on that line and see if `e.Index == -1`.